# I created a filter box in webpage, Javascript code calls data from a json into the filterbox. How to Alphabetize the data?

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter, alphabetical-sort

This code is able to get me my results from the table in a search box. All i want is for it to give me the results sorted by alphabet.

```
 myarray.sort()
```

I tried using myarray.sort(); but it won't go through.

```
function buildLocationList(features) {
var listings = document.getElementById('listings');
listings.innerHTML = '';

 // Iterate through the list of stores
if(features.length > 0){
features.forEach(function(feature, i){
    var currentFeature = feature;
    // Shorten data.feature.properties to just `prop` so we're not
    // writing this long form over and over again.
    var prop = currentFeature.properties;
    // Select the listing container in the HTML and append a div
    // with the class 'item' for each store
    var listing = document.createElement('div')
    listing.className = 'item';
    listing.id = 'listings' + i;

// Create a new link with the class 'title' for each store
    // and fill it with the store address
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'title';
    link.dataPosition = i;
    link.innerHTML = prop.Project_Name; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "it won't go through". but the `sort()` function works exactly like you want here.

Perhaps you want it to sort with case insensitivity?  if so, a bit more work is required, but not much.

```js
var months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec', 'jan', 'dec', 'feb', 'march'];

months.sort();
console.log("regular sort", months);

months.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});

console.log("case insensitive sort",months);
```